# Validation form in Codeigniter - error in class

Tags: codeigniter

I get error when Codeigniter does validation of form:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in
>   /system/libraries/Form_validation.php on line 320

This is full code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lang', 'Lang', 'required|integer');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'required|trim|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Body text', 'required|trim|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li class="errorLi">', '</li>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
}
```

I get error on line `$this->form_validation->run()`.

Also `form_validation` there is in autoload in CI.

Comment: Does it work if you move error delimiters line?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: Yes, I get error still. May be probles is that I have controller in sub-directrory in directory `controllers` as `/controllers/crm/file.php`. Error is on line: `$this->CI->lang->load('form_validation');` from file `Form_validation.php`

Comment: I think if you remove this line `$this->form_validation->set_rules('lang', 'Lang', 'required|integer');` it will work.

Comment: Or to change field name from `lang` to any value? Tried, does not work

Comment: Daniel Waghorn, I get only error which I posted in question

Comment: Does not work when you removed that line?? check your code.I am 100% sure you replaced lang variable some where..That error message say that.

Comment: Yes, when I have removed